# How to set up DNS shortcut?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I want to make a DNS shortcut that would allow users to type in something like "http://MyPhone" in their browser and have it point to a long internal URL (static URL).  DNS is being provided by a Windows 2008 server.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something that you configure on the DNS server. What you need to do is add a [DNS Search Suffix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778792(v=ws.10).aspx) for the domain in question to all of the clients. This can be done via GPO or handed out by DHCP. Also, by default, domain-joined clients will try and append their default domain to unqualified names.

As an example: if the server that you would like to reach is located at `http://server1.internal.ad.example.com`, you would configure `internal.ad.example.com` as the search suffix on the clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DNS alias (pointing MyPhone to the DNS name of your web server) by selecting New Alias (CNAME) from the Action menu in DNS Manager.

However, you'll also have to configure your web server to recognize the name MyPhone as a distinct web site, and create a redirection from that web site's home page to the URL you want, or, depending on your needs, put the content in question on the home page of that site.  How you do this depends on what web server you're using.